# SQL: composite primary key, constraint on cascade

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I have 3 tables: A, B, C.

- The table A contains the attributes: a (primary key)
- The table B contains the attributes: a, c (both of them compose a composite primary key)
- The table C contains the attributes: c (primary key)

How should I set a constraint to remove the elements of B on cascade, when I remove an entry in A? (using Oracle DBMS).

I have tried this:

```
ALTER TABLE A ADD CONSTRAINT constraint FOREIGN KEY (a) REFERENCES B (a) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

But next error is thrown:

```
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
```

Thanks

**Edited:**

I´ve added two foreign keys to the table B:

```
ALTER TABLE B ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (a) REFERENCES A (a) ON DELETE CASCADE

ALTER TABLE B ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (c) REFERENCES C (c) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Then, I will remove elements in table B, and the entries in A and C are also removed.

Comment: Sorry, I didn´t notice it :)

Comment: You're creating your foreign key the wrong way around. B references A (according to your description)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To meet this requirement:

> Then, I will remove elements in table B, and the entries in A and C are also removed.

You need to make the `B` table a parent table for tables `A` and `C` by a adding foreign key constraint, that references `B` table to  `A` and `C` tables.

Note that the number of referencing columns have to match the number of referenced columns:

```
create table A(
  tab_id number primary key
);

create table B(
  col1 number,
  col2 number,
  constraint PK_Key primary key(col1, col2)
);

create table C(
  tab_id number primary key
);

alter table A add ( col1 number
                  , col2 number
                  , constraint fk_AB foreign key(col1, col2) 
                      references B(col1, col2) on delete cascade);
alter table C add ( col1 number
                  , col2 number
                  , constraint fk_CB foreign key(col1, col2) 
                      references B(col1, col2) on delete cascade);
```

Comment: I think it is not possible to add a foreign key in A using col1 and col2, because col1 and col2 are not attributes from A. The same can be applied to C.

Comment: @LuisAndrésGarcía If table `A` as well as table `C` does not have candidates for a composite foreign key constraint add additional columns. According to your question tables `A` and `C` have one column (primary key one), maybe there are another columns, but you've decided not to mention that. So that is why `alter table` statements in the answer add 2 columns, that are going to be a part of a composite foreign key constraint, and constraint itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a guess, but I am assuming table `B` is a child of of both `A` and `C` (perhaps `B` is a bridging (or cross-reference) table between `A` and `C`, where `A` and `C` share a many to many relationship).

```
Table A  \*---1  Table B  1---\*  Table C  (* = many, 1 = one)
```

I also notice that the `FK` you are introducing in an identifying `FK` (by virtue of `B(a)` being a part of `B`'s primary key).

That makes Table A the parent in this relationship, and B the child.  In my experience, any FKs need to be added to the child side of the relationship (in this case, table B).

I'm no Oracle expert, but does this not make more sense?...

```
ALTER TABLE B ADD CONSTRAINT constraint FOREIGN KEY (a) REFERENCES A (a) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

This should remove all `B` rows referring to the PK of any `A` rows you choose to remove.  BUT, I'm not an Oracle expert, so take only at face value until someone with Oracle smarts can confirm (or bomb) my explanation.